# Line-based parser with empty lines and attributes, how to ignore attribute

Tags: boost, boost-spirit

I'm using boost spirit to parse a line-based format, where empty lines are allowed. For this, i'm using something similar to the following grammar:

```
struct parser_type : public qi::grammar<std::string::iterator, qi::ascii::blank_type, std::vector<int>()>
{
    typedef std::string::iterator Iterator;

    parser_type() : parser_type::base_type(main)
    {
        element = qi::int_;
        line %= element | qi::eps;
        main %= +(line >> qi::eol);
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, int()> element;
    qi::rule<Iterator, qi::ascii::blank_type, int()> line;
    qi::rule<Iterator, qi::ascii::blank_type, std::vector<int>()> main;
} parser;
```

This works fine, since the `qi::eps` together with the `qi::eol` matches empty lines. Nice (though i am open to other, perhaps better approaches to parse line-based formats with empty lines). However, the attribute of the `line` parser is an `int`, which is obviously not present on empty lines. Therefore, for an input of

```
1


4
```

the parser creates a vector with the content `{ 1, 0, 0, 4 }`.

I want the line totally ignored, that is, i don't want any dummy object to be constructed to match the attribute of the line. Can this be done? Is there a better way to parse lines?

Here is a complete minimum example (the program needs a input file called "input", you can use my example above):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct parser_type : public qi::grammar<std::string::iterator, qi::ascii::blank_type, std::vector<int>()>
{
    typedef std::string::iterator Iterator;

    parser_type() : parser_type::base_type(main)
    {
        element = qi::int_;
        line = element | qi::eps;
        main %= +(line >> qi::eol);
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, int()> element;
    qi::rule<Iterator, qi::ascii::blank_type, int()> line;
    qi::rule<Iterator, qi::ascii::blank_type, std::vector<int>()> main;
} parser;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("input");
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << file.rdbuf();

    std::string str = buffer.str();
    auto iter = str.begin();
    std::vector<int> lines;
    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(iter, str.end(), parser, qi::ascii::blank, lines);

    if (r && iter == str.end())
    {
        std::cout << "parse succeeded\n";
        for(auto e : lines)
        {
            std::cout << e << '\n';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "parse failed. Remaining unparsed: " << std::string(iter, str.end()) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule:

```
    line = element | eps;
```

causes you to loose the information you need. By *accepting* no-match (`eps`), you force it to just return the value-initialized attribute you declared (`int` in the rul signature).

So, drop that, and then I usually write this kind of a repeat using the list-operator (`%`):

```
    line = element;
    main = -line % qi::eol;
```

This works:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84bd17befbd03ba1)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>    
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct parser_type : public qi::grammar<std::string::iterator, qi::ascii::blank_type, std::vector<int>()>
{
    typedef std::string::iterator Iterator;

    parser_type() : parser_type::base_type(main)
    {
        element = qi::int_;
        line = element;
        main = -line % qi::eol;
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, int()> element;
    qi::rule<Iterator, qi::ascii::blank_type, int()> line;
    qi::rule<Iterator, qi::ascii::blank_type, std::vector<int>()> main;
} parser;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("input");
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << file.rdbuf();

    std::string str = buffer.str();
    auto iter = str.begin();
    std::vector<int> lines;
    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(iter, str.end(), parser, qi::ascii::blank, lines);

    if (r && iter == str.end())
    {
        std::cout << "parse succeeded\n";
        for(auto e : lines)
        {
            std::cout << e << '\n';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "parse failed. Remaining unparsed: " << std::string(iter, str.end()) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Prints

```
parse succeeded
1
4
```